# How to search a dictionary for a value then remove the record that contains that value?

Tags: swift, dictionary

In the program that I am currently writing I have an object called Model with several attributes. One of these attributes is a UUID called model_UUID. I store all of my Models in a dictionary called Models, and I was able to display them in a single section of a tableView without any problems.

Then I wanted to sort the display into sections based on another attribute of the Model, namely codexName. I was able to do this by sorting the original dictionary into a second two-dimensional dictionary with the following code

```
var presortedModels = models
    var sortedModels: [SortedModel] = []
    while !presortedModels.isEmpty {
        guard let referenceModel = presortedModels.first else {
            print("all models are sorted.")
            return []
        }

        let filteredModels = presortedModels.filter { (model) -> 
Bool in
            return model.codexName == referenceModel.codexName
        }

        presortedModels.removeAll { (model) -> Bool in
            return model.codexName == referenceModel.codexName
        }
        let append = SortedModel(codexName: 
referenceModel.codexName, models: filteredModels)
        sortedModels.append(append)
    }

    return sortedModels.sorted {$0.codexName < $1.codexName}
```

This also works without issues.

Now I am wanting to delete a selected model from my table and this is where I am running into an issue. I had thought that since the UUID is unique to each model, reguardless of what section it is in the tableView that I could just look for the UUID in the original array and remove it. Once removed I could call the sorting function again and use the new sortedModels to populate my tableView. I am running into the issue that the model will only be removed if it resides in section 0 of the table view. Attempting to delete any other model will kick out the text for if the UUID was not found. Here is the code I am currently using

```
if editingStyle == .delete {


        // Delete Model from models
        let removeUUID = 
sortedModels[indexPath.section].models[indexPath.row].model_uuid

        if 
(self.models[indexPath.row].model_uuid.contains(removeUUID)) {
            //print("model removed from model array")
            self.models.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        } else {
            print("UUID not found within models")
        }
        // Delete Model from SortedModels
        sortedModels[indexPath.section].models.remove(at: 
indexPath.row)

        // Delete the row from the data source
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)

        // check to see if the section is empty, if it is delete 
the section
        if sortedModels[indexPath.section].models.count == 0 {
            print("this section is scheduled for demolition")

        }
        // Save Changes
        saveModels()
        sortedModels = sortModels()

        tableView.reloadData()
```

TLDR: How can I search through a dictionary for a specific value and if it is found, remove the record it resides in.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help you, it's a generic method but you can adapt to your case.

```
var posts: [[String:String]] = [
["a": "1", "b": "2"],
["x": "3", "y": "4"],
["a": "5", "y": "6"]]

for (index, var post) in posts.enumerate() {
post.removeValueForKey("a")
posts[index] = post }

/* This will posts = [
["b": "2"], 
["y": "4", "x": "3"], 
["y": "6"]]*/
```

Comment: Sadly this didn't do what I needed it to do. Thank you for the idea though.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish my goal by using the following code

```
// Delete Model from models
let removeUUID = 
sortedModels[indexPath.section].models[indexPath.row].model_uuid

models = models.filter { (model) -> Bool in
    return model.model_uuid != removeUUID
}
```

This code takes the UUID from the selected cell, then filters everything that matches that UUID out of the original array.